# Error '3086' could not delete from specified table but read/write rights are there

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want to delete a subtopic from a table under the condition that it is associated with a specific topic in another table.

The topic is selected using a text field in a form.

I assumed I need a `INNER JOIN`, but my delete function would return:

> "error 3086-could not delete from specified table" error

My research showed that this is normally the case if it is a read-only table, but I can manually delete entries in the table, and so I should have write permissions as well.

My Code:

```
'delete all entries from skillsTbl
strDeleteAllSubsFromSkillsTbl = "DELETE TeamSkillsTbl.* " & _
"FROM TeamSkillsTbl, SubTopicTbl " & _
"WHERE (((TeamSkillsTbl.SubTopicName)=[SubTopicTbl].[SubTopicName]) " & _
"AND ((SubTopicTbl.Topic)=[Forms]![frmAdd_Rename_Delete_Topic]![TopicName]));"
```

Code with `INNER JOIN`:

```
'delete all entries from skillsTbl
  strDeleteAllSubsFromSkillsTbl = "DELETE TeamSkillsTbl.* " & _
"FROM TeamSkillsTbl INNER JOIN SubTopicTbl ON TeamSkillsTbl.SubTopicName = SubTopicTbl.SubTopicName " & _
"WHERE ([SubTopicTbl].[Topic]=[Forms]![frmAdd_Rename_Delete_Topic]![txtTopicName]);"
```

Where did I make a mistake?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following instead:

```
DELETE FROM TeamSkillsTbl
WHERE 
TeamSkillsTbl.SubTopicName IN 
(
    SELECT SubTopicTbl.SubTopicName 
    FROM SubTopicTbl 
    WHERE SubTopicTbl.Topic = [Forms]![frmAdd_Rename_Delete_Topic]![TopicName]
)
```

Comment: works perfectly, thank you very much @Lee Mac! I really appreciate your effort.